# My python virus generation code has an issue

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that will count how many viruses there are after some time. Specifically, the original virus will begin to multiply after 120 sec, then every 60 sec, and it's 'offspring' follow the same pattern. With this, I am trying to find how many viruses there are after 879 seconds. The code below should execute every one second, and count how many times it executes until it reaches 879 seconds, but I keep getting an error. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
import time

maxtime = 10 

Arr = []

def virus():
    virus_count = 0
    count_time = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        virus_count += 1
        count_time +=1
    if count_time > maxtime:
        Arr.append(count)
        print('There are', Arr, 'viruses')
        
while True:
    virus()
    
virus()
```

Comment: "I keep getting an error" is not a specific question - please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You *don't actually have to wait for a second* to simulate this...

Comment: At least one of the ``while True`` loops will consume memory until your program crashes. You haven't defined the ``count`` which is appended to ``Arr``, either.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to actually "wait" to simulate this (though I guess you could if you wanted to.

I'm going to keep track of the "age" of each virus in terms of generations. I'll reframe the task as to split viruses only if they are older than 1 generation.

```
generation_time = 60
max_ticks = 879
geration_count = max_ticks // generation_time

# start with a single baby virus
virus_ages = [0]

for _ in range(geration_count):
    ## Age each virus by a generation
    virus_ages = [v+1 for v in virus_ages]

    ## viruses older than one spawn a new virus
    virus_ages.extend([0 for v in virus_ages if v != 1])

print(len(virus_ages))
```

This gives me `610` which I hope if the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I believe that does not take into account the maturation time of 120 sec, am I incorrect?

Comment: It does. a virus aged 60 seconds does not reproduce, only those 120 seconds and older.